# how to call the c static library in a cocoa app?

Tags: cocoa

I have two projects, a Cocoa application and a static c library which it uses.

Then didn't in the same folder.For example:the name of c static library is libXXX.a,it in the XXXcore folder.the cocoa application in another folder that is the same level with the XXXcore folder. When I try to compile the cocoa application,I have the link error result.It is seem to change the search path in the cocoa app info(General panel).But it is not work,why?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Xcode, you can add a link to static library by adding the library to Frameworks folder in the project.

Answer (score 3):

ok. I have the answer:

1. add the .a library to your cocoa project
2. edit the path of Header Search paths and Library Search paths in the project info panel(build panel)
3. don't forget the copy option while adding the library to your project.

Thanks Mehrdad Afshari for your help!